# How can I improve ansi-color rendering performance?

Tags: font-lock

Previously I posted this question to Stack Overflow regarding [rendering ansi-colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378271/how-do-i-display-ansi-color-codes-in-emacs-for-any-mode). The tip worked but performance very bad; when I open a 15 MB log file, emacs just locks up.

I decided to try installing `tty-format.el`. This had the same result (i.e. poor performance).

Then I tried to install [`xterm-color.el`](https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color) but I couldn't figure out how to make it work; the lisp file loaded but it's not clear to me how to make ANSI codes colorize.

**Is there a solution for poor performance in rendering ANSI colors?** Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a (sanitised) sample which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: n.b. Obviously not 15 MB of sample, but something representative of the issue when repeated enough times. e.g. `seq 10000 | xargs -I{} cat sample.log >>verybig.log`

Comment: re: xterm-color.el, looks like it works on strings only. You could try applying it to the result of `(buffer-string)`, but it would likely be even slower (the fact that it works on strings implies the author was only considering colorizing short texts, not whole files).

Answer (score 2):

[Reportedly, using text properties instead of overlays improves performance noticeably](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=29854#11):

```el
(let ((ansi-color-apply-face-function
       (lambda (beg end face)
         (when face
           (put-text-property beg end 'face face)))))
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was way more fun than expected to look into !

The function used in the solution described in your link,

> `(ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))`

is the one to go for in my opinion as it is the function used in comint-mode itself, so I guess pretty "low level" and well integrated in emacs.

One idea would be to apply it only on the visible region by replacing `point-min` and `point-max` by `window-start` and `window-end` and putting it into the `window-scroll-functions`:

```
(require 'ansi-color)

(defun my-colorize-buffer-window (win)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (window-start win) (window-end win t)))

(defun my-colorize-buffer (win _start)
    (mapc #'my-colorize-buffer-window (get-buffer-window-list (window-buffer win) nil 'visible)))

(add-hook 'window-scroll-functions 'my-colorize-buffer)
```

(I copied the way `linum-mode` updates line numbers)

Though using that on a 323Mo log file seems to have good performance (smooth and no freeze when it works), I am still facing some issues with that solution.

In particular:

- infinite loops that go away when resizing frame
- infinite loops that do not go away when resizing frame
- some ansi sequences do not decode right away but only on the second scroll showing them
- `ansi-color-apply-on-region` actually modifies the buffer's contents, whereas `format-decode-buffer` with `tty-format` doesnt. It might by worthy looking into that.

Have to go now, I might update later on !

Comment: No idea about the loops, but the decoding glitches do not surprise me.  After all, ANSI escape sequences consist of more than a byte, so you could end up cutting off the beginning or start of one which would lead to it not being recognized.  The easiest way of fixing this is to start decoding from the beginning of the buffer, the very thing you wish to avoid...

Comment: As for `format-decode-buffer`, it reimplements `with-silent-modifications` for whatever reason.  Yay, old code.

Comment: "(I copied the way `linum-mode` updates line numbers)" - maybe look at how [nlinum-mode](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum.html) works? It's description says "This is like linum-mode, but uses jit-lock to be (hopefully) more efficient."

Comment: @waxamasa: I know about this issue but it is not the case. It is a different one as the sequence itself is decoded only the second time I display this text (ansi not decoded -> scroll up -> scroll down -> ansi decoded)

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color

It's noticeably faster than ansi-color.el and now supports interactive
buffer colorization (via M-x xterm-color-colorize-buffer).

Answer (score 1):

> Then I tried to install xterm-color.el but I couldn't figure out how to make it work; the lisp file loaded but it's not clear to me how to make ANSI codes colorize.

Here's the relevant part of my config, if it's helpful:

```
(use-package xterm-color
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq comint-output-filter-functions
        (remove 'ansi-color-process-output comint-output-filter-functions))

  (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (add-hook 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions
                        'xterm-color-filter nil t))))
```

This gives me ANSI colours in `shell-mode`, although some programs need to be "tricked" into emitting colours, e.g. by using `TERM=xterm-256color`, since `shell-mode` defaults to `TERM=dumb`. Pretending to be xterm can cause problems though, since applications might try to use fancy things like ncurses which `shell-mode` can't handle.